# Interpreting the phrase "lip faces down" in technical documentation

Tags: nouns, terminology, technical

The data sheet for the solvent filtration apparatus includes the following illustration for the assembly procedure:

[image: Assembly instructions]

I'm not sure how to orient the part in the middle, a stainless steel screen.
According to the scheme, its lip must face down, however I'm sure as to what counts as a "lip" here, exactly: an extended part of the metal o-ring, or the side of the ring that is leveled level with mesh:

[image: Side 1][image: Side 2]

My understanding is that the orientation on the right is the correct one as in this case the metal mesh is also leveled with the membrane filter surface, but I'd appreciate a literate interpretation.

Comment: "Lip" in this sense means an extension.  The top photo shows the lip extending upward from the screen.

Comment: You've confused *documentation* with *document*. There's no such thing as **a** technical documentation because there's no such thing as **a** documentation. *Documentation* is a mass noun just like most *-ation* words. The count noun is simply *document*.

Comment: @tchrist Good point, thank you for your correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The edge of a hollow container or an opening.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/lip)

Common example: A cup has a lip and it is often also referred to as a rim. In your case, it is the protruding side that moves away from the mesh; so, yes, the mesh side would go up and the side with a void would go down.

Answer (score 2):

I THINK it means that the lip (as seen in the second picture)is at the bottom and the clear view of the mesh (third picture) should be at the top.

I say this as the membrane filter will need the support of the mesh as seen in the third picture.